The Optical theorem: P&S section 7.3
I'm studying about the optical theorem in QFT with P&S textbook.
I was trying to find the discontinuity of $\mathcal{M}(s)$ in $\phi^4$- theory (p.233).
More specifically, I was calculating the scattering amplitude $\mathcal{M}(s)$ for following diagram,

Then integrand has four poles at $q^0 = \pm (1/2) k^0 \pm(E_{\vec{q}} - i \epsilon)$.
In the next page of text book, for integration over $q^0$, they closed the contour downward and pick up the residues of the poles in the lower half-plane.

In the middle of texts, they said

"Of these, only the pole at $q^0 = -(1/2)k^0 + E_{\vec{q}}$ will contribute to the discontinuity."

So my question is Why the pole at at $q^0 = (1/2)k^0 + E_{\vec{q}}$(on the right side in the lower half-plane) does NOT contribute to the discontinuity of the scattering amplitude $\mathcal{M}(s)$?
Also, I can't relate that poles to the 'branch-cut of spectral density'.

Please don't use images or screenshots for text and math. Instead, type the relevant passage using MathJax.

Thank you for your advise! I'll try to fix it! (* Is there any reason to use MathJax instead of images? May be copyright policy?)

Hi. Some reasons are stated and discussed here.
